# Selenium remote webdriver failing with class cast exception

Tags: selenium, remotewebdriver, selenium-grid2

I my tests working calling the selenium grid server.   but now they're all failing with a class cast exception. (can't cast a string to a map).   Stepping through the Selenium code the response coming from the selenium grid server is some html (telling me I'm using selenium2, as if I didn't know this) as opposed to a map of raw capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to add **/wd/hub** to the end of the Selenium Hub URL.

For example, if your Selenium Hub is running on localhost port 4444 you would use this URL:

```
http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
```